# Validators bound to one datasource activating when changing the edit mode on another

Tags: xpages

I've got a repeat control with a series of documents, and below that on the same panel but outside the repeat control I have another bound document that is new.  The new document has blank fields, but the fields have validation which requires content when the new document is submitted.

That works.

I've added an "edit" button to the repeat entry panel on the repeat control.  The action is to pop that entry ento edit mode.

That works - and I can confirm that the individual rows on the repeat can toggle between edit mode independently, and that when toggling, the new document below does not toggle. It is left alone.

However,

If I have validation code on the new document, it triggers (which fails validation) on the new document even though I'm toggling one of the other bound documents in the repeat.

I have tried to make sure the button is set to partial refresh, and is only set to refresh the individual entry panel within the repeat, and I've tried to make sure the buttons are only bound to the right documents.

It appears to be only the validation code that is at issue, since if I disable it all the toggling works fine and the new document area does NOT create an empty new document in its target database.

Clearly I am missing something.  Any thoughts?

If you want code, I've posted a stripped, sanitized, and annotated version as short as I could make it without removing the related bits here:

```
<xp:repeat repeatControls="false" var="devices" id="ExistingDevicesList" rendered="true">
  <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript: /* Some script that populates the repeat */ }]]>
  </xp:this.value>


  <xp:panel id="IndividualDevice">    <!-- ************ start of the individual device panel -->
    <xp:this.data>
      <xp:dominoDocument var="devDocument"
        databaseName=" xxxxx.nsf" action="openDocument"
        formName="device"
        documentId="#{javascript:devices.getDocument().getUniversalID();}"
        ignoreRequestParams="true" />
    </xp:this.data>


<!-- ******************* The Edit Button ****************** -->

          <xp:button value="Edit" id="button1">
            <xp:this.binding><![CDATA[#{javascript:
    var IndividualDevice:com.ibm.xsp.component.UIPanelEx = getComponent("IndividualDevice");
    IndividualDevice}]]>
            </xp:this.binding>

            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick"
              submit="true" refreshMode="partial"
              refreshId="IndividualDevice">
              <xp:this.action>
                <xp:changeDocumentMode mode="edit" var="devDocument"> 
                </xp:changeDocumentMode>
              </xp:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler>
          </xp:button>             

<!-- ******************************************************* -->

          <xp:inputText id="inputText4" value="#{devDocument.field1}" />       
          <xp:inputText id="inputText5" value="#{devDocument.field2}" />
  </xp:panel>      
</xp:repeat>

<!--  ********** below is a field and button bound to the NewDevice Document -->

<xp:inputText id="inputText3" value="#{NewDevice.field1}"
  style="width:371.0px" required="false">
  <xp:this.validators>
    <xp:validateRequired
      message="You must enter a value." />
  </xp:this.validators>
</xp:inputText>    
<xp:button value="submit new device" id="newDevButton">
  <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
    refreshMode="partial" immediate="false" save="true"
    refreshId="NewDevicePanel" />
</xp:button>    
<!-- ************************************************************************ -->
```

Comment: I'm going to answer my question here!  yea!

I came across the direct answer here on [TOMMY VALAND's blog](http://dontpanic82.blogspot.com/2010/03/xpages-making-validation-behave.html)

The short answer is, the validation is NOT properly bound to the event being related to the specific doc.  That is, in my opinion and major and stupid flaw.

Tommy describes a work around that looks good.

Comment: From what I can tell, Tommy's method doesn't work for me.  It starts to work ok but once validation fails the flag gets set on the front end client side that the field is invalid and required and no amount of clicking on the other mode button stops the client side validation happening.

As best I can tell, you'd have to also code some client side event based code to strip required tags off the client side field.

I'm stunned that IBM has failed to bind the validation event properly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try addind the following settings to your Edit button:

execMode="partial" execId="IndividualDevice"

This will ensure that the partial refresh only runs on the IndividualDevice panel, so the validation on the NewDevice datasource is not run. This will also be better for performance, because it reduces the elements in the component tree (server-side map of the XPage) being processed by the partial refresh.

I was able to reproduce your problem with the code, but when I added the above properties, I was able to toggle documents in the repeat successfully.

Comment: Fantastic!  Thanks.  I can't wait to try that out.

Comment: OK, so setting execMode="partial" execId="IndividualDevice" on the BUTTON itself, did not do it, however selecting "[x] Set Partial Execution Mode" did.   You get credit for the win, because your explanation led me right there.   THANKS!

Comment: Now...off to go eat some crow.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was being thick! Obviously it's a property of the eventHandler, because that's what's doing the partial refresh, not the Button. ;-)

Comment: **"it's a property of the eventHandler, because that's what's doing the partial refresh"**    _this is the critical learned lesson here I think_

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the button with which you save Doc1 to psrtial update to a panel which covers the fields of Doc1. 
From my experience, validators only fire for fields that are in the panel that is being updated.

Furthermore, you can enable and disable any validator st any time. So for each validator, you could enable them only if for example requestScope.doc1IsSaved is true. In the save action, you set requestScope.doc1IsSaved to true or false before saving.

Comment: Julian, thanks for that.  I did exactly as you say to no effect (its in the posted source that way).  I think it may be just the client side validation that fails, though I haven't had time to test that yet.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to follow the JSF (in the end xPages is just something on top of JSF) way of validating form fields. See below code for an example. For validator parameter you can either use Server-side JS, or Expression Language. Although it may be better to use validation methods in backing beans (see: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jsf3/)

```
<xp:inputText value="#{document1.txtServerName}"
    id="txtServerName1"
    required="true"
    validator="#{ServerBean.validateServerName}">
</xp:inputText>
```

UPD: Below is the code of the managed bean I used in my example:

```
package test;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.component.UIInput;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

public class ServerBean {

    public ServerBean() {

    }

    public void validateServerName(FacesContext context, UIComponent toValidate,
            Object value) {
        String serverName = (String) value;

        if (serverName.indexOf('@') == -1) {
            ((UIInput) toValidate).setValid(false);

            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Invalid Server Name");
            context.addMessage(toValidate.getClientId(context), message);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: It may help you because instead of relying on xPages framework, you make use of functionality available in JSF engine, and which allows for much better of validating data in forms. Again, it's another option.

Comment: Alright.  I think, Egor, that I don't yet have the experience to recognize how your example would be used to only fire validation events when the particular data source they're tied to is being updated.  Tommy's code does come close, but the client side validation doesn't keep in sync with the server side using his method from what I can tell.